# Optimal way to search a std::set

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stl, set

How should one search a std::set, when speed is the critical criterion for his/her project?

[set:find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/find/)?

Complexity:

Logarithmic in size.

[std::binary_search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/binary_search/)?

Complexity:

On average, logarithmic in the distance between first and last: Performs approximately log2(N)+2 element comparisons (where N is this distance).
On non-random-access iterators, the iterator advances produce themselves an additional linear complexity in N on average.

Just a binary search implemented by him/her (like [this](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/binary-search-c/) one)? Or the STL's one is good enough?

Is there a way to answer this theoretically? Or we have to test ourselves? If someone has, it would be nice if (s)he would share this information with us (if no, we are not lazy :) ).

Comment: Search on what criteria?  Must it be a `set`?  Is this homework, hence strange rewuirements?

Comment: @Yakk no it isn't. Well I want to have something that insertion and search will be FAST. Also the elements must be unique. I thought of `std::set`, because of the uniqueness and of the sorting, which would provide fast look-ups. The second idea I had was to use a `map`, but maybe this is too much.

Comment: You won't beat logarithmic complexity for `std::set` that is offered by  `std::set::find`, certainly not with a non-random-access iterator and `std:binary_search`. If you want *potentially* better than logarithmic *and* order is *not* important (all that is important is the key lookup), then consider a [`std::unordered_set<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) instead, but keep in mind its *worst* case is linear.

Comment: @WhozCraig I didn't know about this DS. Seems to be the optimal (in the average case), so I will probably go with that. You can see the needs of me in my previous comment.

Comment: @G.Samaras the average-case constant-time search makes it a formidable alternative to consider if you have key data that hashes to a reasonable distribution. If it really is that critical this *specific* part of the code be fast, it is at least worth investigating and doing some benchmarks with real-world data you're be apt to process as keys. Best of luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iterator type provided by `std::set` is a [`bidirectional_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/BidirectionalIterator/), a category which does not require random access to elements, but only element-wise movements in both directions. All `random_access_iterator`'s are `bidirectional_iterator`s, but not vice versa.

Using `std::binary_search` on a `std::set` can therefore yield `O(n)` runtime as per the remarks you quoted, while `std::set::find` has guaranteed `O(logn)`.

**So to search a `set`, use `set::find`**.

Answer (score 1):

It's unlikely that `std::set` has a random access iterator. Even if it did, `std::binary_search` would access at least as many nodes as `.find`, since `.find` accesses only the ancestors of the target node.